# Calling a static function on a nested typedef

Tags: c++-cli

This code refuses to compile:

```
#include <vcclr.h>

struct contained
{
    typedef System::Int32 type;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    auto a = System::Int32::Parse("0");
    auto b = contained::type::Parse("0");

    return 0;
}
```

It fails with

```
C2510   'type': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
C3861   'Parse': identifier not found
```

On the `auto b` line. However, if I bind `contained::type` to a non-nested typedef, it works, and it also works if I change `System::Int32` to my own type. Also IntelliSense doesn't underline the code, so could this be a compiler bug?

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. Version?

Comment: @YSC Visual Studio 2017 (v141), SDK 10.0.16299.0

Comment: It is not a compiler bug. Your code is buggy. Which `#include`s and `using namespace`s are there?

Comment: @S.M. Behaves the same even with no `using namespace` and just `#include <vcclr.h>`

Comment: Post the whole code that doesn't compile, not just a description of what your code looks like.

Comment: It is strange that you have a big enough reputation in Stack Overflow and you are not able to post the minimum, complete and reliable example.

Comment: Ah, the welcoming C++ community again. Better now?

Comment: Get rid of the `stdafx.h`, turn off precompiled headers, and use the real headers (not stdafx.h)

Comment: Not good enough. What does `stdafx.h` contain?

Comment: @S.M. It is strange that you are good at pointing out irrelevant details, yet you cannot read a single comment.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before. I work around it with:

```
typedef contained::type contained_type;
auto b = contained_type::Parse("0");
```

I'd call it a compiler bug but I'm not a lawyer.